# @@identity doesn't work when the table in another server using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I need to get the last identity value from a table but it doesn't work. Usually I use `@@identity` but now I moved this table to another server and it doesn't work I get value NULL.

Have anyone a solution or any idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linked server/openquery consider [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```
INSERT INTO tab(col1, col2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id_col
VALUES ('a', 20);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24b0c7701222fe4603e62cd42425d0bf)**

Comment: @user2586714 . . . More generally, ALWAYS use `OUTPUT`.  It just works.  You don't need to think about it.

Comment: TBH: It depends what you are planning on using it for. If you are doing a singleton insert and want to reference the value later in the TSQL script `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (rarely is `@@IDENTITY` what you need anyway) can be less cumbersome to work with as no need to declare a table variable to output the single value into